# How to find gross value on the IMDB page

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

With Beautifulsoup, i find the vote value on the page with

```
vote = container.find('span', attrs = {'name':'nv'})['data-value']
```

how do i find the value for the Gross, because its the same span name?

Page is [Released between 2018-01-01 and 2018-12-31](https://www.imdb.com/search/title?release_date=2018&sort=num_votes,desc&page=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Not very pythonic way to do things but I kinda played with it.**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def get_imdb_data(url):
    data = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text)
    divs = soup.findAll('div', {'class':'lister-item'})
    movies = []
    for div in divs:    
        movie = {}
        movie['name'] = div.find('h3').find('a').text
        spans = votes = gross = None
        try:
            spans = div.findAll('span', {'name':'nv'})
            try:
                movie['votes'] = spans[0]['data-value']
            except:
                pass
            try:
                movie['gross'] = spans[1]['data-value']
            except:
                pass
        except:
            pass
        movies.append(movie)
    return movies

url = 'https://www.imdb.com/search/title?release_date=2018&sort=num_votes,desc&page=1'
data = get_imdb_data(url)
print(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

perhaps use [`findAll`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#The%20basic%20find%20method:%20findAll(name,%20attrs,%20recursive,%20text,%20limit,%20**kwargs)) and select the second item to get the value of the Gross field. For example:

```
elements = container.findAll('span', attrs = {'name':'nv'})
votes = elements[0]['data-value']
gross = elements[1]['data-value']
```

Comment: I don’t know how to do that

Comment: Try using `findAll` instead of `find` as above.

Comment: That doesn’t work. Probably I have to loop through elements.

Comment: yeah pretty much, and you can do this different ways: for i in range(0,len(container),2):
    e = {'vote' : container[i].text,'gross': container[i+1].text}
    vals.append(e)

Comment: or [{'vote':a,'gross':b} for a,b in zip(_with,_without)]

Comment: where container is obviously: container = soup.find_all('span', attrs ={ 'name':'nv' })